# Answer for "What is your name?"

Tags: idiomatic-language

Could somebody answer the question "What's your name?" with "It's John" or would it be better to say "My name is John" ?

Comment: "Bond. James Bond."

Comment: @StoneyB but only if you expect him to die, not talk.

Comment: if anyone says 'what's your name?' refuse to answer. When asking for someone's name, especially for the first time, it is 'what is your name?' - you have no idea who the other person might be to risk using abbreviated speech.

Comment: Don't refer to yourself with "it". Use "I" (I am John).

Comment: @user3169 Yes, but by all means refer to your name as *it*, though!

Comment: What is my name? It is the proper noun I use to identify myself.

Answer (score 1):

`It's John`.

```
My name is John.
I'm called John.
John.
```

All the above are good.